# Once a CNN is trained, should its ouputs be deterministic?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I just trained a CNN with Tensorflow/Keras and saved it as a model.  I tried running about 1000 inputs through it multiple times, and each time got a slightly different prediction accuracy.  The accuracy was good, and I am not concerned with the performance; however, I thought that CNN models, once trained, should be deterministic.  That is, any input will always be classified the same way.  Is this not the case?  Is there variability in the way a model can predict once trained?  If not, hopefully I can assume that I have programmed some variability into my code unawares.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Assuming Tensorflow can run the model multithreaded, which could affect the order of mathematical operations, which in turn could affect the precise effect rounding errors have on the final result, I would not expect the output to be precisely exactly the same with each trial, down to the last bit. It should be within the margin of rounding error though, taking the entire chain of computations into account.

Comment: Do you have batch normalisation in your model?

Comment: If you do have batch normalisation in the graph the problem could be that the layers are updating with the batch statistics rather than using the frozen values.

Comment: Thank you. I do have batch norm, however, I don't know that I understand it well enough to discern if this is the issue.  I thought that the parameters added by batch norm were fixed after training.

Answer (score 2):

> Once a CNN is trained, should its ouputs be deterministic?

Well, in theory, yes. In practise, as Peter Duniho points out in his excellent explanatory comment, we can see **very** small deviations because of the way values are calculated, aggregated, etc.

In practice the probability of such small deviations changing the predicted category (and therefore the accuracy) of a classification model are so small that I'd be almost certain something else is at play in your example. Even over a sample size of 1000.

Have you left on some training regularisation like batch normalisation? Are you certain you are evaluating precisely the same 1000 inputs each time? Got to suspect the issue is in the code rather than rounding errors.

Can you determine which specific classification changes?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Yes, I have left on batch normalization.  I guess I don't understand how batch normalization works.  Are the parameters added by batch norm not fixed after training? Also, yes I am certain I have been evaluating the same set of inputs each time.